# PyQt4, Python 3.4 on Windows 7

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, windows-7-x64

I ran the windows 64bit installer for PyQt4 pointing it to the python34 folder.  Python is not in default location, so I added PYTHONPATH with D:\Program Files\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4

Added the import statement to my module: "from PyQt4 import QtGui".  I execute and get: "from PyQt4 import QtGui ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."

I noticed that if I simply put import PyQt4 and use intellisense in IDLE there are only a few private methods visible.

Since I ran the installer, must I still perform a make?  Readme references windows instruction that do not seem to be present on my machine.

Comment: I guess the version of PyQt does not match the version of Python, you should download and install PyQt for Python34

Comment: the correct installation doesn't require setting PYTHONPATH wherever python is. You could try [a binary installer instead](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt) for your Python version.

Comment: Thank you, J.F.  The UCI website has a binary that works perfectly with py3.4.0.    I could not find one earlier.

Comment: Read this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32054021/how-to-install-sip-pyqt-on-windows-7/47144239#47144239