# How to install SIP & PyQT on windows 7

Tags: python, python-sip

I'm a newbie to Python environment & really struggling to install SIP & PyQt on my Win 7 machine.

*This is what I've done so far,*

1. I've downloaded [SIP-4.16.9](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download) and extracted files from the zip folder
2. The extracted folder is then copied to [C:\Python34\Lib](http://C:%5CPython34%5CLib)
3. Launched a command prompt(cmd) and changed path to **C:\Python34\Lib**
4. Then when I entered `python configure.py` at **C:\Python34\Lib** and I get the response as below

[image]

5. At this stage I'm not sure whether it's been installed successfully, to verify I looked for **SIP.h** at `C:\Python34\Include`(according to above response - in red), but I cant find any such header file, so I assume the installation hasn't been successful.

***Could any one help me, what am I missing here?***

#### Additional System Info:

- Windows 7 64 Bit
- Python 3.4
- Environment Variable (Path : C:\Python34;C:\Python34\Lib;C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages)

**Note**: There are several questions posted before, but none of them helped so far, I'm sure I must be missing something silly.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Personally I gave up on maintaining my own python environment a while ago and took the easy way out and run Anaconda now.  It's a python distribution that has QT, NumPy, SciPy, IPython, PyTables, pandas, Matplotlib, scikit-learn, and other packages already configured and good to go.  Check it out at http://continuum.io/downloads#py34

Comment: From the [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/installation.html#building) it sounds like the next step after configuring is to build it. Suggest you try that and then ask a question if there's a problem.

Comment: @ Check Thanks for the link, I had this while ago & removed when some one suggested me to use PyCharm.

Comment: @martineau, `make` didn't work. I get an error message as "`make` is not recognised as an internal or external command", thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: So now you've discovered an even more fundamental problem — which is that you don't have the C/C++ compiler and `make` utility needed to build the extension. You may also need to download the source code for the version of Python you're using.

Comment: I'm sure I have got C/C++ compiler installed along with VS 2012 Professional version, by the way what does this `make` do? is it a DOS related command?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*For next users who need to build sip (or pyqt) in windows using sources*

***ALL these instructions are for 32-bits, it will work even if you have a 64-bit system.***

## For Qt 5.9.x :

Since Qt 5.9, there is only one version of Qt downloadable for Windows that includes the pre-built components for MSVC201x and MinGW.

The instructions follow the same steps as for Qt 5.8

Since *Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition* is not available to download anymore, next users should use *Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition* with Qt 5.9 and follow the same instructions below.

1. *Microsoft Visual Studio 2017* Community Edition (32-bits)

   - https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/
2. *Qt 5.9.x*

   - http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/

When Installing Qt, make sure to select the correct pre-built components you have (for e.g Microsoft Visual Studio 2017)

[image]

## For Qt 5.8 and earlier :

### Downloads

1. Download *Python 3.6.x (32-bits)* any version will do it :

   - https://www.python.org/downloads/

(if you also have python 2.7, make sure to use verions 3 of python)

2. Download *sources for sip and PyQt5*: Under *"Source Packages"*, download the *"Windows Source"*

   - https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download
   - https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5
3. *Microsoft Visual Studio 2015* Community Edition (32-bits)

   - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48146
4. *Qt 5.8.0 for Windows 32-bit* (VS 2015, 1.0 GB)

   - http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/

Qt download link must match the Visual Studio (VS) version installed (here VS 2015) and the PyQt5 version you need to install

For example:

- PyQt5.8.2
- Qt5.8.0 (Link for VS 2015)
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2015

## Compilation

**Open a terminal and stay on it.**

**It is important you stay on the same terminal (`cmd.exe`) during the whole process so you don't have to source your environment twice.**

Let's create an environment to compile PyQt and SIP (in order to compile PyQt, you need first to compile sip)

- Create a folder "compilation" in your Desktop for example:
- Extract the content of your sip archive in this forlder
- Extract the content of your PyQt5 archive in this forlder

You should have now :

```
.
├── compilation
|   ├── sip-4.19.2/
|   └── PyQt5_gpl-5.8.2/
```

Make sure you are using Python 3.x:

[image]

#### 1 - SIP

Go to *sip-4.19.2* folder and run :

`python configure.py`

[image]

At this step, you did not install sip, you only configured it (basically its installation dir, etc...)

**VERY IMPORTANT STEP: source your environment variables by running in the terminal :**

Keep the double quotes, windows does not like spaces ...

[image]

```
"C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0\5.8\msvc2015\bin\qtenv2.bat"
```

After running this command, it automatically change your current directory, stay on the terminal and re-go to your sip-4.19.2 directory and run:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
```

**In windows, "make" is substituted by "nmake" !**

Then (always in the same terminal) you run :

```
nmake
```

[image]

[...]

[image]

```
nmake install
```

[image]

This will create a sip.exe in your Python dir, for me it is `C:\Python36`, it may elsewhere, depending on where you installed Python.

#### 2 - PyQt5

The steps are almost the same as sip but it will take more time.

Go to *PyQt5_gpl-5.8.2* folder and run :

`python configure.py --disable QtNfc --confirm-license`

Note that this command disable QtNfs because of a compilation problem I could not resolve.. and automatically accepts the license.

Then, run (the compilation will take a while) :

```
nmake
nmake install
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is very helpful.  At the `nmake` step, in `~\VC\bin`, I used: `nmake c:\python27\path_to_sip_makefile\Makefile` but get an error message: `cd sipgen  NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code 0x1 Stop.'

Comment: Are you running `nmake` from your sip dir (where you runned `python configure.py`) ? because I don't remember having specified a Makefile with `nmake`. If you still have issues we can have a chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135711/build-sip-in-windows

Comment: I'm running `nmake` from its directory (in `~VC\bin`).  I know it's finding the `Makefile` because the first line in the Makefile is `cd sipgen`  Do I need to have some kind of special compiler installed?

Comment: Thank you for the stright forward post! Makes a lot of sense. I am hitting a issues with version mismatches during the nmake. The error message I am getting is: fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'               How should I go about debugging this

Comment: @jspada, you will have to install all elements either 32bits or 64bits, you cannot mix (e.g MVS2015 64bits and Qt 32bits)

Comment: Thanks! I did not realize I had python 64 bit installed, not 32, which was tripping me up.

Comment: Ok, based on the last few comments, I am using msvc2015_64 and also using vcvars64.bat and I am able to compile until the last line where I am given the error:
"'mt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file."

I am assuming this is not in my path and I have to find it, is this correct?

Comment: Found the mt.exe in Windows SDK, v7.1a, x64.

Answer (score 3):

There's a ONE SHOT solution to all your installation problems on Windows. Go to this website. http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. Navigate to the library you want and download the .whl file for your python version and your computer (32 or 64 bit.) Then run `pip install YourWhlFileName.whl`, and you're done! (CAUTION: MAKE SURE NOT TO CHANGE THE NAME OF THE WHL FILE OR IT WON'T WORK.)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but before I try this I really want to figure out the issue and find a fix.

Comment: It's a great resource and has saved my ass multiple times, but it doesn't host any wheels for sip whatsoever...

Answer (score 0):

This is for all that want to build PyQt4 with latest Qt4 and Python 3.4.x.

Download Visual Studio 2010 from here:
http://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-Visual-Studio-2010-Ultimate/3000-2383_4-75450998.html

then install it.

Download SIP source code (in my case version 4.19.5) from here:
https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download

Download PyQt4 source code (in my case version 4.12.1) from here:
https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download

Extract SIP and PyQt .zip archive in \Users\your_username\Desktop\compilation\

Download latest Qt 4.x (vs2010 version) installer from here:
http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/

Install Qt (in my case qt-opensource-windows-x86-vs2010-4.8.6.exe).

Open a command prompt (use this one for all the process) and execute these commands:

```
cd \Users\<your_username>\Desktop\compilation\sip-4.19.5
python configure.py
"C:\Qt\4.8.6\bin\qtvars.bat"
```

In the output take note of QMAKESPEC value, in my case win32-msvc2010, then use it later on --spec option for PyQt4 configure-ng script.

If the current directory has been changed, execute again:

```
cd \Users\<your_username>\Desktop\compilation\sip-4.19.5
```

Now, if you use 64-bit version of Python execute:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
```

otherwise, if you use 32-bit version of Python execute:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"
nmake
nmake install
cd \Users\<your_username>\Desktop\compilation\PyQt4_gpl_win-4.12.1
```

Now use previous QMAKESPEC value in --spec option:

```
python configure-ng.py --spec win32-msvc2010
nmake
nmake install
```

That's all ;-)

**NOTE**: in some cases, in order to avoid this error

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

it is necessary to copy .dll files from

```
C:\Qt\4.8.6\bin
```

to

```
C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4
```