# PyQt built on Windows: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: qt, pyqt, nmake, python-sip

I've tried to build PyQt from sources (with binary Qt 5.8.0 downloaded) on my Windows 7x64.

I did it by this tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40779370/2726900

I've entered Visual Studio 2015 Command Prompt, activated `vcvarsall.bat amd64`, activated `qtenv2.bat`.

Than I configured, built and installed SIP (no errors).
Than I configured PyQt (just added `--sip C:/Python35/sip.exe`) and successfully built and installed PyQt.

The filed like `QtCore.pyi`, `QtCore.pyd`, `QtGui.pyi`, `QtGui.pyd` and so on really appeared in my `site-packages/PyQt5` folder.

Bug when I tried to import some modules from my installed `PyQt5`, it failed.

```
>>> from PyQt5 import QtGui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Cannot you tell me, how can I fix it?

Comment: Hmm... A added my `Qt5` folder with DLLs to PATH and nothing changed. Than I simply copied the contents of the folder with `Qt5` DLLs to my PyQt5 folder, and it started working... But how can I avoid such copying?

Answer (score 1):

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pyqt5
```

Comment: While this might be a correct solution, answers are better when you explain them instead of just dropping a block of code.