# PyQt5 DLL load failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, importerror, dllimport

First off, i know this has been asked quit often like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863505/dll-load-failed-when-importing-pyqt5) and in many other posts[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739191/pyqt5-pyuic-import-error-dll-load-failed) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44710033/pyqt-built-on-windows-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-fou) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43218064/pyqt5-5-8-2-doesnt-function-on-windows-10) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601611/cant-get-pyqt5-running) . I read all of the posts on this and other forums but none did resolve my issue or i did not understand where excatly i need to copy some missing dlls? I hope to find some guidance .

I recently installed python on win10 via the microsoft store. The version is Python 3.7.4.
When i type "where python" i get the following result:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

The packages are installed via pip to:

```
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37
```

When i try to import PyQt5 (which installed via pip without any error) i get the following result:

```
>>> from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

I do see the PyQt5 packes in the "site-packages" folder.

I read somewhere that qt5 is not compatible at all with python in its current version. Is this correct? If so what would you advise me to use instead? At the moment i just want to create a small gui for a matplotlib bases plotting tool that needs to additional options like fileinpout and a few clickable buttons to choose options.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have Python 3.7 and PyQt5 on my Windows7 machine and it works. I am not sure about Windows 10 though

Comment: I am running this on `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.439]` and when I type `where python` I get the following to lines: `C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe` and `C:\Users\djensen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe` so not sure why you are getting all the extra baggage and I can import PyQt just fine

Comment: Would you be willing to show me the corrspoding entries of python in your PATH variable and if existent in PYTHONPATH? I simply installed python from the micorsoft store and thats were it put allt the files... Later i installed packages via pip.