# Installing sip for Python on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-sip

I have a new machine (windows 10) and am running Python 2.7.13 (64 bit). I have managed to install a couple of modules, but now am having an issue with sip, which I need before I can install PyQt4.

I downloaded the zip file, extracted the folder to C:\Python27\Lib\sip-4.19.3.
I then opened a cmd and cd into C:\Python27\Lib\sip-4.19.3 and ran:

```
python configure.py
```

I got this in the cmd window:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\sip-4.19.3>python configure.py
This is SIP 4.19.3 for Python 2.7.13 on win32.
The SIP code generator will be installed in C:\Python27.
The sip module will be installed in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages.
The sip.pyi stub file will be installed in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages.
The sip.h header file will be installed in C:\Python27\include.
The default directory to install .sip files in is C:\Python27\sip.
Creating siplib\sip.h...
Creating siplib\siplib.c...
Creating siplib\siplib.sbf...
Creating sipconfig.py...
Creating top level Makefile...
Creating sip code generator Makefile...
Creating sip module Makefile...

C:\Python27\Lib\sip-4.19.3>
```

But when I open IDLE and try and import sip I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import sip
ImportError: No module named sip
```

I did a print out of my modules:

```
['pillow==4.0.0', 'pip==9.0.1', 'setuptools==28.8.0', 'wheel==0.30.0']
```

So I know its not there but I am unsure what I should do after running the configure.py.

I looked online and saw that it may be that I need to build sip after the configure.py has been run so tried I tried typing make after the initial configuration but got this:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\sip-4.19.3>make
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Python27\Lib\sip-4.19.3>
```

The installation documentation is a little ambiguous and makes some assumptions so I would like to know what I should do after the configure.py as I am a bit stumped.

Thanks

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32054021/how-to-install-sip-pyqt-on-windows-7

Comment: Thanks, still having a little bit of an issue, but I will work it out

Comment: The page I was linked to does not really provide the solution as its about Python 3 and PyQt5. It also says I need vs2015 community, so I am not sure that is the best page to follow as I do not recall doing that before. All I need is a proper explanation of how to install sip for python 2.7 on a windows 10 64 bit machine as I said in my original question,.

Comment: Did you get this figured out?  I'm running on to the same issue.  I need to use the older versions of python and sip because they match the requirements of 3ds Max.