# Install PyQt and SIP for Python3.6 on Windows7

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, python-3.6, python-sip

I found **TONS** of answers online but nothing helped. I found this question:

> [How to install SIP & PyQT on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32054021/how-to-install-sip-pyqt-on-windows-7)

Which kind of helped but I got stuck on this part:
[(Step I Got Stuck On)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeOYF.png)

After pasting `"C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0\5.8\msvc2015\bin\qtenv2.bat"`into my cmd it said that `The system cannot find the path specified`. Also, I tried skiping ahead to see if the further steps work for me. The command `nmake` didn't work either. What am I missing?
I'm using:

- Windows7
- Python3.6
- sip4.19.4
- PyQt5.9.1
- VisualStudio2017

Also, please don't mark this question as a duplicate of the question linked above as I did read it but I had troubles with doing what the answer said.

Comment: why not `pip3 install pyqt5`?

Comment: @ingvar Tried that. Pip does not realy work for me. Do I need to add it to my PATH or something? If so, what location should I add (or what location is it at)?

Comment: During installation you can check option "Add Python to PATH". If for some reason you didn't checked it you have to add it manually. Check python in one of default installation dirs listed here: https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html

Comment: @ingvar turns out Python is in my path but when I type in `py pip3 install pyqt5` it kindly informs me that `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python32\python.exe can't open file 'pip3': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.
When I try to execute that command in the python shell it tells me `invalid syntax`
 Any suggestions?

Comment: Just open console and type `pip3 install pyqt5` (`pip install pyqt5` should also work). Note that pip3 is somewhere in `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3‌​2\Scripts`, it's also must be in PATH. Or you can open console, cd to pip3 dir and type `pip3 install pyqt5`.

Comment: @ingvar, thank you, now we're getting somewhere. While pip3 does not work, pip alone does but instead of installing pyqt5 it tells me that it `could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5`. I also tried just pyqt and pyqt4. Nothing worked. Should I somehow update pip?

Comment: what about `pip install PyQt5`?

Comment: @ingvar nope still no :(

Comment: are you sure you're using pip for python3, not pip for python2.7?

Comment: @ingvar sorry, how can I tell? And if I am, how do I get the one for python 3.6?

Comment: open cmd, type `python --version`

Comment: It says that I have python2.7.13 (???).

Comment: seems that you have python2.7 in PATH, not python3.6

Comment: I went to where the path was and I have the following files there: pip, pip2.7, pip2. I'm guessing I'm supposed to have pip3.6 in there somewhere right? Where can I get it?

Comment: @ingvar I looked around the internet some more and found this `py -m pip install <Your desired package>`. This seems to work. For some reason it does not work when I type in what you said. any idea why?

Comment: did you find where pip3 is located?

Comment: @ingvar Do you mean the pip3.exe file. I did not find it :( .

Comment: try to reinstall python36

Comment: Hi, sorry about the late reply. Reinstalling python didn't seem to help much. I tried using python --version again and i got 2.7 again ._. Should I uninstall Python2.7? if so, how do i go about that because it does not seem to be in the ControlPanel programs list?