# Installing SIP (for PyQt5) on Windows 10 with VS 2017

Tags: windows, python-2.7

I've used the answer here with success on previous installations but hitting a roadblock this time: [How to install SIP & PyQT on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32054021/how-to-install-sip-pyqt-on-windows-7/32054867)

I get an error on the `nmake` step (see below):

```
C:\source>cd sip-4.19.9

C:\source\sip-4.19.9>python configure.py
This is SIP 4.19.9.dev1804161501 for Python 2.7.14 on win32.
The SIP code generator will be installed in c:\python27.
The sip module will be installed in c:\python27\Lib\site-packages.
The sip.pyi stub file will be installed in c:\python27\Lib\site-packages.
The sip.h header file will be installed in c:\python27\include.
The default directory to install .sip files in is c:\python27\sip.
Creating siplib\sip.h...
Creating siplib\siplib.c...
Creating siplib\siplib.sbf...
Creating sipconfig.py...
Creating top level Makefile...
Creating sip code generator Makefile...
Creating sip module Makefile...


C:\source\sip-4.19.9>"C:\Qt\5.10.0\msvc2015\bin\qtenv2.bat"
Setting up environment for Qt usage...
Remember to call vcvarsall.bat to complete environment setup!

C:\Qt\5.10.0\msvc2015>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"

C:\Qt\5.10.0\msvc2015>cd \source\sip-4.19.9

C:\source\sip-4.19.9>nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24234.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    cd sipgen
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24234.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    cd siplib
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24234.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

       cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -O2 -MD -W3 -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -Ic:\python27\include -Fo @C:\Users\suzanne\AppData\Local\Temp\nmB36B.tmp
siplib.c
apiversions.c
descriptors.c
qtlib.c
threads.c
objmap.c
voidptr.c
array.c
int_convertors.c
Generating Code...
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -O2 -MD -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -I. -Ic:\python27\include -Fo @C:\Users\suzanne\AppData\Local\Temp\nmB8AB.tmp
bool.cpp
        link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DLL /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:sip.pyd.manifest /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /INCREMENTAL:NO /OUT:sip.pyd     @C:\Users\suzanne\AppData\Local\Temp\nmB939.tmp
   Creating library sip.lib and object sip.exp
        mt -nologo -manifest sip.pyd.manifest -outputresource:sip.pyd;2
'mt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'mt' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio     14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...

mt.exe part of Visual Studio's Windows SDK, which wasn't installed.  Went back and installed it through Get Tools and Features.

Then found \x86\mt.exe and added it to path.